"moved to chat" links broken
It seems at least some "moved to chat" links are broken, example http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70394/discussion-on-answer-by-gilles-public-randomness-based-random-number-generator-u
This is from extended comments on question Public Randomness-Based Random Number Generator using Mobile Phone?
Is this a known issue? Or are chat links supposed to be decomissioned after a certain time?

I have undeleted the room in question.

For me this "feature" implies that mods should never move comments to chat.

Agree, auto deletion basically means these sometimes very useful comments are lots to the public forever

Actually this room still exists (at least for mods), after 8 days of inactivity (that is 183 days ago) and with less than 15 messages it has just been automatically "deleted". Mods can not only see such rooms but also undelete them. So if you want to see the contents of such a room, simply make a post here on Crypto.Meta, ping a mod in our chat or in the comments of the post whiches comments were moved to chat and we'll undelete it (even though it will probably re-delete itself after 7 days...).
However right now I'm unsure whether there is actually a "point of no return" where the room is actually deleted from SE's systems.

As discussed in comments above, will mods consider _not_moving comments to chat in the future simply based on volume? Doing so effectively deletes all the.comments as far as end users are concerned!
